# Show multiple menu buttons over each thumbnail in gallery on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery of thumbnail images whose paths are dynamically loaded from a file and organized in rows of 5 using `float:left`. Each row is separated by `<br style="clear:both">` tags.

I want to display navigation buttons specific to each image over each image on hover.

I have been following [this tutorial approach](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity) to try to add buttons over images.

Each image has a Javascript generated `img_container` tag structured like this which will eventually have navigation commands tied to each button:

```html
<div class="img_container">
    <img class="menu_image" src="/houses/1.jpg">
    <div class="menu">
        <button>Floor Plan</button>
        <br>
        <button>History</button>
        <br>
        <button>Ownership</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS used to organize and space the images:

```css
img {
    width: 295px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

As can be seen in the attached photos, the image dims on hover as on the tutorial demo page but because of the `float: left`, the buttons appear in the same absolute position middle of the page no matter what image is hovered over.

I tried to make `.menu` have `float: left` as well and this positioned the buttons near their image but also made the `.menu` div take up unwanted space rather than float over the image.

How can I make each individual image container's buttons appear over it's image?

[image]
[image]

Comment: float:left should ONLY be used in an emergency.  It's just not a good technique except in a few special cases.  Use flex or grid to position your images and use absolute positioning to position your navigation buttons.  If you added a working snippet you might get a better answer

Comment: Thanks. A few modifications to [this display: grid example](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/css/grid/examples/photo_gallery_auto-fill_evenly_sized_images) caused the `.menu` div to be positioned almost exactly where I needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick here is to realize that you can't hover over a hidden element.  wrap what you want to hide in a span.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img_container {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  align-items:center;
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:100px;
}

.menu button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu:hover button {
  visibility: visible;
  width:80px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="img_container">
    <img class="menu_image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200">
    <div class="menu">
      <button>Floor Plan</button>
      <button>History</button>
      <button>Ownership</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img_container">
    <img class="menu_image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x200">
    <div class="menu">
      <button>Floor Plan</button>
      <button>History</button>
      <button>Ownership</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got it working with your `display: grid` hint on the question but you provided exactly what I couldn't find after hours searching the web: a functioning example that does what I needed.